# Changing the title of a specific command button based on its tag

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uipickerview

I am relatively new to Xcode and I need some help. So, my view has 2 buttons (it has more buttons, but for simplicity's sake, let's say 2) which are all connected to one IBAction. When pressing each button a Picker appears loaded with an array depending on which button gets pressed. I would like for the title of the button to match what the user selected in the PickerView.

I know I have to modify some code in the `pickerView:didSelectRow` method but I don't know how to do it. The way it works now is that no matter which button I click (I should note the correct array loads up, so that part works correctly), button with tag "0" gets modified with the content of the selected Picker row. So I need the button at the SELECTED tag to be modified.

My header file is:

```
@interface XYZSecondViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate,   UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *myPicker;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;

- (IBAction)myButton:(id)sender;

@end
```

My implementation file:

```
#import "XYZSecondViewController.h"
@interface XYZSecondViewController ()
  @property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray *myArray1;
  @property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray *myArray2;
  @property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray *chosenArray;
@end

@implementation XYZSecondViewController
@synthesize myButton, myPicker;

- (IBAction)myButton:(id)sender
{
    switch ([sender tag])
    {
        case 0:
            self.chosenArray = self.myArray1;
            break;
        case 1:
            self.chosenArray = self.myArray2;
            break;
    }
    [self.myPicker reloadAllComponents];
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row   forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
      return [chosenArray objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:  (NSInteger)component
{
      [myButton setTitle:[chosenArray objectAtIndex:row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could track the tag for the button currently tapped.

Something like this:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger tagLastTappedButton;

...

- (IBAction)myButton:(id)sender
{
    tagLastTappedButton = sender.tag;
    ...
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:  (NSInteger)component
{
      UIButton *buttonTapped = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:tagLastTappedButton];
     [buttonTapped setTitle:[chosenArray objectAtIndex:row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take one integer in you header:

```
int flag;
```

Modify you switch case:

```
switch ([sender tag])
    {
        case 0:
            self.chosenArray = self.myArray1;
            flag=0;
            break;
        case 1:
            self.chosenArray = self.myArray2;
            flag=1;
            break;
    }
```

and in your `didSelectRow` make an `IF` statement like:

```
if (flag==0) {
    [myButton1 setTitle:[chosenArray objectAtIndex:row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}else{
    [myButton2 setTitle:[chosenArray objectAtIndex:row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: I think this wouldn't work because I don't have "myButton1", "myButton2" etc. I just have multiple buttons which are all called "myButton" but are different by their Tag property. Am I correct?

Comment: But in your question you are saying that I have two buttons so you have to take two separate IBOutlets and connect each of them respectively.

Comment: No, but I said "which are all connected to one IBAction". I just set different Tag values for each of the buttons. Anyways, small misunderstanding :)